# MP4 file, Recorded on two seperate devices, One person to loud the other to soft

Tags: sound

MP4 file, the sound for the video has been created with two different devices. One person was recorded by a mic connected to a video camera, the other was recorded on the laptop. Now when I play the video one person is to loud the other I can hardly hear. Cn I edit this somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to manually automate the volume levels on a Daw or you video editing software.

Maybe a compressor could help too.